# Filter by array of Objects searchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have created an searchController and therefor i'm trying t make it filter content according to the text in the UISearchController. I've created a custom Object looking like below. I've tried using NSPredicate, but keep getting:

`cannot convert value of type NSPredicate to expected type @noescape (organization) throws...`

```
class Organization: Object {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var shortName: String = ""
    var image: NSData = NSData()
    var pinImage: NSData = NSData()
    let locations = List<Location>()

}
```

Then I have an array called `sortedLocations` in my ViewController which contains a number of `Organization` Objects.

What I've tried so far:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

    let array = sortedLocations.filter(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [Organization]



    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `filter()` method of `SequenceType` does not take an `NSPredicate`
as an argument, but a *closure*, e.g.

```
let filteredTableData = sortedLocations.filter {
    $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchText)
}
```

The closure is called for each array element (here using the shorthand
argument `$0`) and returns `true` or `false` to indicate if the element
is to be included in the filtered result or not.

---

You can use an `NSPredicate` to filter an `NSArray`, that would look
like

```
let filtered = someNSArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

but there is no reason to use this if you have a Swift array.

Comment: hmm but `filteredTableData`, doesnt seem to contain anything when i write something which is contain in an object name? Do i need to append anything?

Comment: @PeterPik: I have just double-checked it with  a small test program and it worked as expected.

Comment: but shouldnt i append anything aswell?

Comment: @PeterPik: Sorry, I don't understand. Append what? `sortedLocations` is the "full" array with all organizations and `filteredTableData` is the filtered array with organizations whose name contains the given search string.