# Search property from class in array within UITableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsarray, uisearchcontroller

Context: Swift, iOS8-9, UITableView, UISearchController. 
Code based on this example: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let scores = (allScores as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = scores as! [Score]
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Problem: my data are from a class `Score` which has a property `name` and that is what I need to look in (ideally `name` and `topic`, but with `name` I'd be happy for now). So `allScores as NSArray` is not working because `Score` does not contain text, but the `name` property does. How can I implement that here? Something like `allScores.name` is obviously not working, but I don't know how to call the name property of all items in an array in general.

Comment: Why NSArray and NSPredicate? Use the Swift filter method on the Swift array directly. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767274/filter-by-array-of-objects-searchcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `NSPredicate`, derive your `Score` class from `NSObject` and simply use the property name in the predicate (no `SELF` required).

```
class Score: NSObject {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    override var description: String {
        return self.name
    }
}

let allScores = [Score(name: "a"), Score(name: "ab"), Score(name: "b")]
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", "b")
let scores = (allScores as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
print(scores)
```

The above snippet prints `[ab, b]` on the console.

However, you can achieve the very same result by using Swift's `filter` method.

```
let allScores = [Score(name: "a"), Score(name: "ab"), Score(name: "b")]
let scores = allScores.filter { $0.name.containsString("b") }
print(scores)
```

This snippet again prints `[ab, b]` on the console which demonstrates its equality to the `NSPredicate` variant.

Comment: This worked, although I needed `let filteredScores = allScores.filter{$0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("b")}` to make it work properly :-)