# i am trying to do filter search using array and using search controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

```
func filterContentForSearchText(SearchText : String, scope:String = "All"){
        let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "job_title contains[cd] %@", SearchText)

        let resultJobs = SavedJobs.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
        FilteredJobs = NSMutableArray(array: resultJobs)
        FilterResults = FilteredJobs.filter{
            FilterJobs in
             return FilterJobs.name.lowercaseString.containsString(SearchText.lowercaseString)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

This is my func for `filterContentForSearchText` and it is working fine, the only problem i am having is that when i click on search bar it returns empty array and app terminates saying index 0 is beyond array bounds as array is empty further my `numberOfRowsAtIndexPath` is below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if SearchController.active && SearchController.searchBar.text != ""{
            return FilterResults.count ?? 0

        }

        return SavedData.count ?? 0


}
```

further my `cellForAtIndexPath` is below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SavedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SavedJobsCell

        if SearchController.active && SearchController.searchBar != ""{
            if let rowData: NSDictionary = FilteredJobs[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary{
                cell.CompanyName.text = rowData["company_name"] as? String//FilteredJobs.valueForKey("company_name") as? String
                cell.Location.text = rowData["location"] as? String//FilteredJobs.valueForKey("location") as? String
                cell.Date.text = rowData["created_date"] as? String//FilteredJobs.valueForKey("created_date") as? String
                cell.JobTitle.text = rowData["job_title"] as? String//FilteredJobs.valueForKey("user_logo") as? String
                if let image = rowData["user_logo"] as? String{
                    let ImageUrl = NSURL(string: ("http://dev.jobsmarket.pk/uploads/user-logo/"+image))
                    cell.ComapnyIcon.sd_setImageWithURL(ImageUrl)
                }
            }
        }
        else{
        let PremiumJob = SavedData[indexPath.row]
        cell.CompanyName.text = PremiumJob.valueForKey("company") as? String
        cell.JobTitle.text = PremiumJob.valueForKey("title") as? String
        cell.Location.text = PremiumJob.valueForKey("location") as? String
        cell.Date.text = PremiumJob.valueForKey("date") as? String
        var ImageName = String()
        if let image = PremiumJob.valueForKey("user_logo") as? String{
            ImageName = "http://dev.jobsmarket.pk/uploads/user-logo/"+image
        }
        let ImageUrl = NSURL(string: ImageName)
        cell.ComapnyIcon.sd_setImageWithURL(ImageUrl, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "JobAvatar"), options: [])
        }
        return cell
    }
```

i am using predicate and it is giving me null array for the first time when i tab on search bar, by which table recieve null array and throws error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter by array of Objects searchController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767274/filter-by-array-of-objects-searchcontroller)

Comment: that problem was diffrent, that is related to using predicate